# Image on TableView which is retrieved from CoreData

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data

I want to display an image that is being retrieved from core data and every single cell will have a different image. I have done this but I do not know how to retrieve from this path and place the image into the cell. Anybody can help me on this? Thanks in advance.

```
 NSString * filePath = @"01.jpg";
NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:filePath], 0.1);
[productInfo setValue:imageData forKey:@"productImage"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fetch the managed object from your model and place it in the array where the array would contain the photo names as below. I am assuming that your entity be **photoStore** and the column for storing the photo file name be **nameOfPhoto**, so the code would look like,

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest=[[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 
NSEntityDescription *entity=[NSEntityDesription entityForName:@"photoStore" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity : entity];
NSArray fecthedObject = [fetchRequest executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
for(NSManagedOect *photos in fetchedObect)
{
  [self.arrayOfImageNames addObject : [photos valueForKey :@nameOfPhoto"]];
}
```

Now, inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath use the image name to add the image to your cell's imageview as,

```
NSString *imagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString : [[self.arrayOfImageNames objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] stringByAppendingPathComponent:"jpg"]];
cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];
```

This is how you would add the store the image name into core data and then retrieve the name construct a path to it and display it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get path use this -

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"01" ofType:@"jpg"];
```

Comment: i want to retrieve the image from core data and then place it in the UITableViewCell.